# What is the reason why sorting algorithm is stable or unstable?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I want to understand the main reason why sorting algorithm becomes stable or unstable. I understand that every unstable algorithm can become stable if we add one more position key to the element. (But it can effect on speed and memory usage).I also understand that during unstable sorting elements are always change there places.

But what is the main reason of it? Is it because at some cases we use divide and conquer strategy?

Comment: Why any given sorting algorithm is unstable is fairly easy to figure out, and the reason isn't generic for all of them - each works differently and thus most have different reasons.

Comment: @Dukeling So I should ask a question about specific case?

Comment: Yes, you probably should. In any case, the only possible generic answer is "a stable sorting algorithm is stable because it doesn't change the order of elements that compare equal to each other", which is just restating the definition.

Comment: Your assumptions are a little faulty. An unstable algorithm is always unstable, regardless of input; however, just because an *algorithm* is unstable does not mean it will *always* swap elements with equal keys--it simply does not guarantee that equal items will *not* be swapped.

Comment: @chepner If you secondarily sort on the position that the element had in the original input, nothing will be equal, and you'll enforce a correct ordering of (previously) equal elements, thus the sort will be stable. This will, however, only work for comparison-based sorting algorithms. In theory it could also work on other (e.g. numeric / integer-based) sorting algorithms, but you'd likely take a massive hit to time and/or space complexity.

Comment: @Dukeling I should have been clearer; I was just correcting the OP's claim that elements always change places in an unstable algorithm. An unstable algorithm is not one that *always* produces unstable output; it's just an algorithm that is not *guaranteed* to produce stable output when there are duplicate keys in the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the comparisons and swapping that the algorithm uses. Generally if comparisons and swaps occur between far-flung objects in an array, without having looked at the elements in between first, the sort will not be stable.

Comment: I'd probably add something like "without having looked at the elements in between first". Just off the top of my head, both insertion sort and selection sort can have comparisons and swaps from one side of the array to the other, but are still stable (well, selection sort can be made stable).

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason. Stability is just a property, that just exists. Sometimes algorithm is stable by sheer chance (the creator did not have stability in mind). Most of the time algorithm is stable exactly because the creator wanted it so.